# Unexpected missing end-of-source newline

Tags: stylelint

I am getting the above error with `stylint`. How to fix any one help me?

my `scss` file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
/* end of import */
```

Error I am getting:

```
src/components/tabs/tabs.scss
15:16   ⚠  Unexpected missing end-of-source newline (no-missing-end-of-source-newline) [stylelint]

[vite:css] Unexpected missing end-of-source newline (no-missing-end-of-source-newline)
13 |  }
14 |  
15 |  /* empty line */
   |                  ^
```

`stylelint` config:

```
    /* eslint-env node */

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'stylelint-config-standard',
    'stylelint-config-recess-order',
    'stylelint-config-css-modules',
    'stylelint-config-prettier',
    // Uncomment out the below if you want to use scss
    'stylelint-config-standard-scss',
    'stylelint-config-recommended-scss',
  ],
  plugins: ['stylelint-scss'],
  ignoreFiles: [
    './node_modules/**/*.css',
    './dist/**/*.css',
    './coverage/**/*.css',
  ],
  rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignoreAtRules: [
          'tailwind',
          'apply',
          'screen',
          'variants',
          'responsive',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'no-duplicate-selectors': null,
    'no-empty-source': null,
    'rule-empty-line-before': null,
    'comment-empty-line-before': null,
    'selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown': null,
    'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
    'no-descending-specificity': null,
    'string-no-newline': null,
    // Limit the number of universal selectors in a selector,
    // to avoid very slow selectors
    'selector-max-universal': 1,
    'selector-class-pattern': null,
    // --------
    // SCSS rules
    // --------
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-before': 'never',
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-after': 'always',
    'scss/dollar-variable-no-missing-interpolation': true,
    'scss/dollar-variable-pattern': /^[a-z-]+$/,
    'scss/double-slash-comment-whitespace-inside': 'always',
    'scss/operator-no-newline-before': true,
    'scss/operator-no-unspaced': true,
    'scss/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector': true,
    // Allow SCSS and CSS module keywords beginning with `@`
    'scss/at-rule-no-unknown': null,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `no-missing-end-of-source-newline` rule expects a newline at the end of the file. Add a newline to fix the problem:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
/* end of import */
```

(Note the additional newline at the end.)

You should also extend Prettier's Stylelint configs last and there's no need to explicitly use `postcss-scss` or `stylelint-config-recommended-scss` as they are included in `stylelint-config-standard-scss`.

Your config should be:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    'stylelint-config-standard-scss',
    'stylelint-config-css-modules',
    'stylelint-config-recess-order',
    'stylelint-config-prettier-scss'
  ],
  ignoreFiles: [
    './node_modules/**/*.css',
    './dist/**/*.css',
    './coverage/**/*.css',
  ],
  rules: {
    'at-rule-no-unknown': [
      true,
      {
        ignoreAtRules: [
          'tailwind',
          'apply',
          'screen',
          'variants',
          'responsive',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'no-duplicate-selectors': null,
    'no-empty-source': null,
    'rule-empty-line-before': null,
    'comment-empty-line-before': null,
    'selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown': null,
    'declaration-block-trailing-semicolon': null,
    'no-descending-specificity': null,
    'string-no-newline': null,
    // Limit the number of universal selectors in a selector,
    // to avoid very slow selectors
    'selector-max-universal': 1,
    'selector-class-pattern': null,
    // --------
    // SCSS rules
    // --------
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-before': 'never',
    'scss/dollar-variable-colon-space-after': 'always',
    'scss/dollar-variable-no-missing-interpolation': true,
    'scss/dollar-variable-pattern': /^[a-z-]+$/,
    'scss/double-slash-comment-whitespace-inside': 'always',
    'scss/operator-no-newline-before': true,
    'scss/operator-no-unspaced': true,
    'scss/selector-no-redundant-nesting-selector': true,
    // Allow SCSS and CSS module keywords beginning with `@`
    'scss/at-rule-no-unknown': null,
  },
};
```

Comment: Actually, I have a empty line. but do not know the reason. Is my prettier remove it?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address issues in your config.